C don't want to run program properly
So i(a total beginner) tried to run c file on vs code(mac os). By using magic I somehow accessed terminal(i was using debug console before, and it was pain in …). But now it won’t work properly, it’s just stop after i enter first number
Here the code
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    double a,b,c;
    printf("enter number a");
    scanf("a=%lf\n",&a);
    printf("enter number b");
    scanf("b=%lf\n",&b);
    printf("enter number c");
    scanf("c=%lf\n",&c);
    double d;
    d=(sqrt(a*b(a+b+c)(a+b-c))/(a+b);
    printf("result=%lf\n:",d);
    return 0;
}

Here is output
cd "/Users/roman/Desktop/bob/" && gcc test2.c -o test2 && "/Users/roman/Desktop/bob/"test2
roman@MacBook-Air-Roman ~ % cd "/Users/roman/Desktop/bob/" && gcc test2.c -o test2 && "/Users/roman/Desktop/bob/"test2
enter number a12         #here i enter number
enter number benter number cresult=-0.000000 
:%                                                                                                                                                                                         
roman@MacBook-Air-Roman bob %


Please remove the newline from every scanf(), see What is the effect of trailing white space in a scanf() format string? Note too, that scanf() wants to match every character so unless you actually input say a=42 this will fail. The first scanf() should be scanf("%lf", &a);, or even better if(scanf("%lf", &a) != 1) /* handle error */

Is this really the code you are compiling? d=(sqrt(a*b(a+b+c)(a+b-c))/(a+b); won't compile.

For gcc specifically you need to do -lm "link math" whenever you use math.h.

(a*b(a+b+c)(a+b-c))/(a+b)  this seems to be the term you are using to calculate sqrt  and it makes no sense. Operators are missing and parenthesis are missing... About the rest of the code, the specifiers for scanf are just wrong. And scanf returns an int for a reason. Understand such reason and use the return value, instead of just blindly going on
